# How can i create a token for the card in stripe and charge the card for a user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I have created an application in stripe and now i allow user to sign up to my site and after they sign up i would ask them to connect to the stripe using the credentials if they have or signup in stripe and bring back them to the site with the stripe access token.

Now say the other user login and he wants to purchase something that belongs to the other user who has already connected with stripe.

> user1 (connected to stripe)
>
> user2 (wants to purchase a product that is displayed by user1)

So i use the checkout to get the card detail of user2 and the publishable key that i use to create a token is the key of the application  which i created. The token is created and  if i pass on for charging the card then it shows up

```
Invalid token id: tok_1278ghsdg26hsdfs. The publishable key used to create this token is from a different account.
```

and the following is the way i charge

```
token = params[:stripeToken]
charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
    :amount      => @amount,
    :card        => token,
    :description => 'sample desc',
    :currency    => 'usd'
  },
  Accesstoken
  )
```

so how can i charge the card for a customer?

Comment: This is a tough one because Stripe integration in a Rails app is designed to be "Single Tenancy". Each account has different Publishable keys, which means you'll have to find a way to create a new Strip instance for each payment -- something I'm not certain of yet

Comment: Thank you for responding. If you find any thing useful to this topic, please update me so i can make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

You will find some help from here https://support.stripe.com/questions/connect-publishable-key-error-with-shared-customers